# Get model changes on save event

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

If an model/element gets changed then I can know about it by listening to an event like onBeforeSaveEntry. This will provide me with the latest version of the model/event, but doesn't give me the changes. Something like this would be great.

```
craft()->on('elements.onSaveElement', function (Event $event) {
    $element = $event->params['element'];

    // $changes = ['uri' => ['old' => 'index', 'new' => 'index2']]
    $changes = $element->getUnsavedChanges(); 
}
```

I generate a routes.js that the client uses to generate menu and other stuff. I would like to listen to uri/slug changes so I can clear my (varnish) cache to update internal links. I'd like to prevent clearing my whole site if just one tiny thing gets changed. Any idea's how I can get the model changes or work around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to listen to the `onBeforeSaveEntry` event, then query the database for the existing entry (if one exists).

```php
craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $e)
{
    if(!$e->params['isNewEntry'])
    {
        $updatedEntry = $e->params['entry'];
        $currentEntry = craft()->entries->getEntryById($updatedEntry->id);

        if($updatedEntry->getUrl() != $currentEntry->getUrl())
        {
            // Do your thing
        }
    }
});
```

It might also be worth checking if the updated entry even has a URL, so you could skip that DB query if you don't need it.

You have to be careful with this event though - there's always the possibility the transaction could fail and the updated entry won't get saved to the DB. In that case, you might want to also listen to the `onSaveEntry` event (if you're doing anything other than writing to the DB - this would get rolled back automatically if something fails) as a way of checking if everything went okay.